# Conversion of Digital data to Analog data without using A to D / D to A converters

Tags: c++, dll, dsc

I wanted to know how the Analog data (voice) gets converted into digital data on a system(laptop). There are certain H/W which are A to D / D to A converters already present in a system. They do conversion for us. Is there any library through which i can get an access to it?

Work Purpose:

I have a digital data which i need to change to analog data without the help of HW. I need something like Minimodem tool which changes data at some Baud Rate.

My work purpose is , I need to make an application which can build DSC message to audio signal and is capable of decoding it back to digital data.

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The speaker and microphone jacks on your PC are essentially D/A and A/D devices. Google for modems to understand how they encoded bits and you could probably generate a sound stream for transmission. As for decoding such a stream back to digital data, that's probably going to require some amount of digital filter programming.

Comment: You will always need  some hardware. To minimize it, you may have a look at delta-sigma converters. You will get a series of 0 and 1, with a high interpolation ratio. A 1D converter will still be needed

Comment: Our system has a software speech to text, which means an analog data is getting converted to some digital data ,in this case it is text. Which means The Speech to Text application is using some converters which are already present in the system. Can i have an access to the converters which are already present in the system? Is there any library/ Dll  which can serve the purpose stated above?

Comment: Is there any algorithm by which a input data in text , can be converted to audio wave file at some baud rate.